# NumberFormatter works on simulator but not on device swift

Tags: ios, swift, numberformatter

Separate thousands with commas.
On the simulator, everything works perfectly, but on the device, for some reason, the same code, instead of a comma, puts a space.

[image: This is a simulator example]

[image]

[image: This is a device example]

[image]

Comment: For "some" reason? The formatter uses the device's locale (language).
If you want the formatter to use a specific locale, you have to set it explicitly.

Comment: No pictures of code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong, the formatter works correctly both on the simulator and on the device - each just uses a different locale. If this is a number displayed to the user then it's completely correct that the number is formatted in the user's locale.

If you want to use a specific locale everywhere, you have to set it explicitly, e.g.:

```
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped! I wish you well)